# Arduino serial print

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I know this sounds really silly, but I really can't figure it out. I'm loading the following arduino code on an arduino uno:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("HELLO");
}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

I'm uploading the code on the board and if I open a serial monitor repeatedly, I get different outputs. I'm expecting the output HELLO, and I get that sometimes. But I also get outputs like: HELLHELLO or HHELLO. I also loaded the same code on an arduino nano and it behaves similar.

Can someone please explain why this is happening? Is this an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be due to the usb to serial buffer still containing data from the previous reset.

Try storing the string in [PROGMEM](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM) to keep the string in flash memory rather than in RAM and see if that helps.

Comment: Ok, tried something like this: `#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

const char message[] PROGMEM  = {"HELLO"};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println(message);
}`, but unfortunately this prints nothing, so I scrolled more and I read that I can use the F() macro to save the message to flash. `void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println(F("HELLO"));
}` indeed it prints something but wrong again: HELLHELLO

Comment: try putting this before you call print: `while(Serial.available()){Serial.read()};` It should clear the buffer

Comment: ok, done. it still happens but now I observed something new. It outputs garbage like "HELLHELLO" only when I open serial monitor after upload. If i  open the serial monitor again it prints "HELLO"  okay each time.

Comment: for future reference, note that there is an Arduino stack exchange and questions like this should really be here http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the baud rate to match to 9600 in the serial monitor, mismatched rates can cause unexpected output like you saw.

[image]